# How to really reduce the opacity of drag effect in pyqt6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt6

I'm trying to create some drag and drop feature with pyqt6. I want to allow the user to drag images from some widgets to another widgets, and I want to make the drag effect seems a bit transparent so that the user can see through the dragged image.

```py
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event) -> None:
        if event.buttons() & Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
            drag = QDrag(self)
            mimedata = QMimeData()
            mimedata.setImageData(self.image)
            drag.setMimeData(mimedata)
            pixmap = QPixmap(QSize(150, 150))
            pixmap.fill(Qt.GlobalColor.transparent)
            painter = QPainter(pixmap)
            painter.setOpacity(0.5)
            painter.drawPixmap(QRect(0, 0, 150, 150), self.image)
            painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), pixmap)
            painter.end()
            drag.setPixmap(pixmap)
            drag.setHotSpot(event.pos())
            self.master.removeImg(self)
            self.deleteLater()
            drag.exec()
```

This is what I have done so far. Doesn't matter how much reduce the opacity with

```py
painter.setOpacity(x)
```

Apparently it just makes the image more white and doesn't interferes in the opacity of the drag effect.

Please help me to really get the drag effect transparent.

Comment: Try removing this line `painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), pixmap)` which redraws the pixmap onto itself and would cause it to be more opaque

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot make "semi transparent" the QDrag icon, it only supports masking. See [qtbug-57173](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57173).